# Is there any way to stretch vector to the same length?

Tags: python, vector, dtw

May I know is there any way to make the two vectors to the same length?

the x-axis is x-axis of a squats movement
the y-axis is time frames

the blue line x is the first squats motion  --> 
the yellow line y is the second squats motion

Is there any way to stretch the yellow line so that the length of the two vectors would be the same.
after we stretch the yellow line, it is better to keep the pattern as before.

I've heard a lot of ways to make two vectors to the same length, like padding zero, signal normalization or embedding, But until now, I still cannot find a good solution.

[image]

it would be very appreciated for your answer.

Comment: If you're plotting (x,y) coordinates, then you should *not* stretch anything; you'd be misrepresenting your data by altering the x-coordinate of each measurement in the yellow curve. You could instead truncate the data in the blue curve, or you could limit the plotting range on the x-axis to not show data points beyond the yellow curve. But "stretching" the data is definitely not what you should do

Comment: You could try simple linear reinterpolation, although in your case DTW might be enough. Check [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/216301292_Everything_you_know_about_dynamic_time_warping_is_wrong).